# run a task after another task has ran

Tags: windows, windows-8, scheduled-tasks

I have two tasks:

1. runs WAMP
2. opens Google Chrome

What I'm trying to do is to trigger task number 2 after task number 1 has already triggered.
After WAMP's task has ran I would like to run Google Chrome's task.

Think of it as a callback function. When task 1 has finished running, trigger task 2.

Note: I'm trying to do that using windows 8.1 task scheduler

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar running WAMP task at `startup` and Google Chrome at `log on`. I've also tried delay, but it isn't good. It has to be one after another

Comment: @SJD there isn't any. I'm using windows 8.1 task scheduler. It is a user interface

Comment: @kfirba Ok. Then you should abstract your question.

Comment: @SJD I've edited the question. Let me know if you need more details

Comment: What about scheduling a .cmd file?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten If it's possible to make a CMD file to start WAMP and only after that start Google Chrome, then I think it's a very good solution. However, I'm not that good with cmd. barely knows the basics

Answer (score 11):

You can Trigger the Task2 with 'On an event' option. Go to (Setting - Custom -Edit Event Filter) and put this code in the XML tab.

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">*[EventData
[@Name='TaskSuccessEvent'][Data[@Name='TaskName']='\Task1']]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: For this to work, you need to have task history enabled. On the right "Actions" sidebar of the task scheduler , `Enable All Tasks History` toggles it (Windows 10).

Comment: Also, don't forget to put the full "path" of the task in place of the TaskName. This full path includes the folders in which the task is.
For example, if in your task scheduler you've created a "MyTasks" folder in which there is a "OnLogOn" folder in which there's is  a task named "Task 1 Hello World", then the TaskName would be:
`'\MyTasks\OnLogOn\Task 1 Hello World'`

Comment: I was unable to find reference for the name of that event but perhaps should it be TaskSuccess instead of TaskSuccessEvent? For me using the `EventData[@Name='ActionSuccess']` yielded the desired outcome and figured perhaps that TaskSuccess is following the same naming pattern :D

Comment: @Jaak Kütt will using `ActionSuccess` make the task start even if the other task failed? Because `TaskSuccessEvent` sounds like it will be triggered only if the task was successful, so in the case the program that the task executed had an error it wont execute this new task, is that right?

Comment: @churchill only if the other task succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, I have Task1 scheduled on my server, now I want to execute Task2 on successful completion of Task1, then create Task2 with trigger as below

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">*[EventData
[@Name='TaskSuccessEvent'][Data[@Name='TaskName']='\Task1']]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

[image: Run Task Scheduler After Another]

Comment: If all you're doing is adding an image to the pre-existing answer, go ahead and edit the answer and add your image.